# How can I check the active window against a list of predetermined window list?

Tags: autohotkey

I working on something and I have this issue where, of all the programs installed on my PC. One set of programs act one way against my code and all the rest act another way. So I am thinking of building a list of problematic programs and do something else only when one of these problematic programs are active.

```
ProblemProgs :=
    (
        ahk_exe sublime_text.exe
        ahk_exe dopus.exe
        ahk_exe notepad.exe
        ahk_exe vivaldi.exe
    )
3::
WinGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, A
    if (A = ProblemProgs)
        {
            MsgBox, Do this
        }
    Else
        {
            MsgBox, Else do this
        }

Return
```

Thank you.

Comment: To get the process name of a window see https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#ProcessName. And to check whether a process name match one of the items in your list see https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm#Examples

Comment: @user3419297 Hey I was able to do it with GroupAdd command. Thanks allot for your suggestion though, I am certain that second link will come usefull.